# How to Validate Azure AD SAML 2.0 Assertion in C# using ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 library

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2, .net-4.6.2

My project technology is ASP.NET Webforms (.NET framework 4.6.2).
We are using "ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0" library for Azure AD SAML Authentication. The sample code present in Itfoxtech website was helpful but, my manager asked me, how you are validating saml assertion once user login was successful? But, I didn't find any documentation regading validating saml assertion when user login successful. can you please let me know how to do that? I am not aware of SAML before, hence, could you please explain in details?

Validating Azure AD SAML Assertion in ASP.NET Webforms applicaiton

Comment: Basically, I want to know how to validate authenticity of Azure Response when using itfoxtech SAML 2.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SAML 2.0 assertion is part of the SAML 2.0 authn response sendt from Azure AD. The ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 library validates the authn response and the assertion. By validating the signature(s), issuer, audience and time.